# How COPY in separate lines helps with less cache invalidations?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) suggests the following as best practice.

> If you have multiple Dockerfile steps that use different files from
>   your context, COPY them individually, rather than all at once. This
>   ensures that each step’s build cache is only invalidated (forcing the
>   step to be re-run) if the specifically required files change.

For example:

```
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY . /tmp/
```

> Results in fewer cache invalidations for the RUN step, than if you put
>   the COPY . /tmp/ before it.

**My question is how, how does it help?**

In either cases, if requirement.txt file doesn't change then `pip install` would fetch me the same result, so why does it matter that in best practice scenario, the requirement.txt is the only file in directory (while doing pip install)?

> On the other hand, it creates one more layer in the image, which is
>   something I would not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a very simple application

```
$ ls
Dockerfile  main.py  requirements.txt
```

With the corresponding Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

Now say you only change the `main.py` script.  Since the `requirements.txt` file hasn't changed, the `RUN pip install ...` can reuse the Docker image cache.  This avoids re-running `pip install`, which can download a lot of packages and take a while.

Comment: yes, but if the docker image directory has `req.txt` and `main.py` at the same time, why or how, docker would invalidate `pip install` cache?

Comment: A `COPY` command invalidates the cache for all following instructions if the specific files it copies changes.  If you change `main.py` but don't change `requirements.txt`, then Docker recognizes that `COPY requirements.txt .` is unchanged from the previous build.

Comment: Thanks @David for replying. Can you direct me to a documentation/blog where it is mentioned that `A COPY command invalidates the cache for all following instructions if the specific files it copies changes.`.

Comment: It's mentioned under "Leverage build cache" in the Docker documentation [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache).